# System error: exec format error when I start a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers

Im triying to start a docker container : 
Docker version :

```
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2

sudo docker run  -p 8080:8080 rancher/server
```

but i got this error message !

```
FATA[0001] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b75d05c38d0f19d59e9c12608c56aac756c1a5bf321ef2cca918e7a7b251904d: [8] System error: exec format error
```

this is my server info using `uname -a` command :

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.13.0-137-generic #186-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 19:12:26 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Docker images :

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
rancher/server      latest              41e01154bc55        2 weeks ago         1.083 GB
```

Could you please advise what might the error that I may be committing or am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, you should tell us which command you used to start the container.

Comment: You're on a 32 bit platform (as indicated by the `i686` in the output of `uname`). Probably the image you are using requires a 64 bit platform.

Comment: so i have to install ubuntu 64 ?

Comment: what's your Docker version?

Comment: Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated in the question comments your Docker version is `1.6.2`. As per [Rancher documentation](http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/hosts/#supported-docker-versions) anything below `1.12.3` is not supported. Update your Docker, best if you update to latest community edition (CE).

The guide how to install/update Docker on Ubuntu is found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Comment: Thank's but i tried to run ubuntu container and i got the same error

Comment: You are on Docker version released on 13 May 2015, what do you expect? It's 2018 now.